# How to do this using jQuery - document.getElementById("selectlist").value

Tags: jquery

In jQuery, what is the equivalent to `document.getElementById("selectlist").value` ?

I am trying to get the value of a select list item.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the down vote for not trying this in google?

Comment: You're likely getting downvotes because your questions could be answered in just a few seconds on Google, or by reading the JQuery docs.

Comment: +1 to tonsils for braving SO's users. His question is a perfectly valid one, regardless how easy/hard it was to solve. More traffic to SO for future searches on this subject.

Comment: c'mon guys - jQuery voodoo isn't all that easy to learn for an old guy like me, server dev that I've been for the past 20 years or so - be nice and go easy on us jQuery newcomers! :-)

Comment: @Boekwurm Ben - he might be brave, but you can't blame the SO users either.  People generally like to see a little effort by the person asking the question.

Comment: As I recall, this was the first thing I didn't get about jQuery. I think its a valid question if truth be told, and marking down was harsh. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75296/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-the-noobs-closed

Comment: I am 10+ year programmer, I just switched to jQuery and this is the **FIRST** problem I encountered.

Comment: Equivalent of `document.getElementById` in jQuery is `$('#myId').get(0)`. This worked for me.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

```
$('#selectlist').val();
```

Comment: Whoa. You got the jackpot LOL.

Answer (score 214):

"Equivalent" is the word here

While...

```
$('#selectlist').val();
```

...is equivalent to...

```
document.getElementById("selectlist").value
```

...it's worth noting that...

```
$('#selectlist')
```

...although 'equivalent' is not the same as...

```
document.getElementById("selectlist")
```

...as the former returns a jQuery object, not a DOM object.

To get the DOM object(s) from the jQuery one, use the following:

```
$('#selectlist').get(); //get all DOM objects in the jQuery collection
$('#selectlist').get(0); //get the DOM object in the jQuery collection at index 0
$('#selectlist')[0]; //get the DOM objects in the jQuery collection at index 0
```

Comment: perhaps a little tangential here, but this would be great info:  is there a way to get the DOM object from the jQuery one?  **edit**: answered my own question in edit.

Comment: I bashed my head against a wall for an hour until I realized that getElementById() can't be replaced by $(). Thank you so much for this answer!

Comment: @knite - Yes. I wish I had someone explain tht to me the first time I used jQuery.

Comment: thanks for the later part explanation of getting DOM objects in jquery :).

Comment: +1 Oldie but a goodie. I was trying to figure out why Google Maps accepted a DOM object but didn't accept my jQuery object. A quick google search led me here, not to jQuery docs.

Comment: And how do you get the jquery from the dom? :)

Comment: Just wrap the DOM object with `$()`

Comment: I have been scratching my head why $('#selectlist') always gave me an "null or not an element" error. Thanks for the clarification. This should be empathized more in tutorials.

Answer (score 9):

Chaos is spot on, though for these sorts of questions you should check out the [Jquery Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) online - it really is quite comprehensive.
The feature you are after is called 'jquery selectors'

Generally you do `$('#ID').val()` - the .afterwards can do a number of things on the element that is returned from the selector. You can also select all of the elements on a certain class and do something to each of them. Check out the documentation for some good examples.

Answer (score 9):

It can be done by three different ways,though all them are nearly the same

Javascript way

```
document.getElementById('test').value
```

Jquery way

```
$("#test").val()          

$("#test")[0].value             

$("#test").get(0).value
```

Answer (score 2):

For those wondering if jQuery id selectors are slower than document.getElementById, the answer is yes, but not because of the preconception that it searches through the entire DOM looking for an element. jQuery does actually use the native method. It's actually because jQuery uses a regular expression first to separate out strings in the selector to check by, and of course running the constructor:

```
rquickExpr = /^(?:(<[\w\W]+>)[^>]*|#([\w-]*))$/
```

Whereas using a DOM element as an argument returns immediately with 'this'.

So this:

```
$(document.getElementById('blah')).doSomething();
```

Will always be faster than this:

```
$('#blah').doSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases of which I can't remember why but `$('#selectlist').val()` won't always return the correct item value, so I use `$('#selectlist option:selected').val()` instead.

Comment: Maybe you could post some links back that confirm this. I would be surprised however. This would be a fundamental bug in jQuery. Is it possible you are using a buggy version of the library?

Comment: Could have been James, I think it could have been in 1.3.0, can't seem to repro in 1.3.2, but it could have also been in IE6 or 7 which I don't have installed anymore, I'll see if I can figure out the original cause and report it here.