# Rails Javascript Empty string passed to getElementById()

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 3.2 app.  The following javascript was working fine.
Now, it's getting `'Empty string passed to getElementById().'`
Also getting `Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.` in the console.

I'm not sure what changed?

```
 $('#costproject_rebudget_funds').change ->
    alert "hey"
    checkbox = document.getElementById('costproject_rebudget_funds')
    if checkbox.checked
      $("#costproject_new").attr('checked', false)
      $("#costproject_rebudget").attr('checked', false)
      $("#rebudgetamount").show()
    else
      $("#rebudgetamount").hide()
      $("#costproject_rebudget_amount").val('')
```

I added the `alert "hey"` for troubleshooting.  It is getting triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use jquery everywhere else except right at the 
checkbox = document.getElementById('costproject_rebudget_funds') line.
Why not get the element using jquery? 
checkbox = $('#costproject_rebudget_funds').get(0) perhaps?
Here is a post possibly talking about some of the issues you are having: [How to do this using jQuery - document.getElementById("selectlist").value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310159/how-to-do-this-using-jquery-document-getelementbyidselectlist-value)

Particularly note the second answer not the picked one.

For your deprecation error i'm unsure because you aren't showing the preventDefault code.